# calendar full with this recurring event

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

It's a few weeks now that I repeatedly find events similar to this in my calendar, everyday the same, forever:

1. I don't know how it gets there
2. I'd like to cancel it without notifying anyone (just to limit feedback to the guy)

has anyone got a clue?

[image: unwanted event]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a Google Calendar, the following advice from https://the-parallax.com/2018/05/11/how-to-stop-calendar-spam/ should help:

> **Google Calendar**: From a Web browser, click on the event in Calendar, but be careful not to reply to it, and not to click on any
>   of the links within it. At the top, under the Going section, click
>   “Report spam.” The event, along with all others from that organizer,
>   will be removed from your Calendar.
>
> To prevent more spam from showing up on your Google Calendar in the
>   future, click the Gear icon in the upper-right corner, and go to
>   Settings. Scroll down to Event Settings, and change Automatically Add
>   Invitations to, “No, only show invitations to which I have responded.”

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to suppress sending notifications from the iPhone or macOS calendar apps. To do this you'll have to go to the Google Calendar web app (https://calendar.google.com), right-click the event, and click Delete.

I can't answer how the event got there, but if you've never declined or deleted it before, that would explain why you're still seeing it.